# Can I change anchors or move images with ARKit and ARSK View?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, arkit

I am trying to build a compass with ARKit, but I am having trouble with moving images. The compass is made up of 4 sprites for each of the cardinal directions, and they each hover one meter away from the camera in their specific locations. I would like the compass to surround the camera, so that even when the user moves, the compass still surrounds them. However, I do not know how to move the positions of these images after they are set for the first time.

I know it is possible to move nodes in an ARSCN View, but I am using an ARSK View, and as far as I know, it is impossible to move an anchor. In what way could I change the positions of the images if I do not move the anchor? Is this even possible with ARSK View, or should I give up and switch to ARSCN View?

Answer (score 0):

Your use case suggests you don't really need elements that "move" in 3D, but elements whose 3D position is fixed relative to the camera. This sort of thing is trivial in a 3D framework like SceneKit, but much harder when you're trying to work in the space between ARKit (which mostly is concerned with world-relative positions) and a 2D framework that "fakes" a 3D effect for 2D content.

In SceneKit, you can make nodes follow the camera by making them children of the [`pointOfView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523982-pointofview) node. Of course, that'll make them follow not just the camera's position but also orientation. If you want to selectively follow some aspects of the camera's transform but not others, you'd do well to combine node hierarchy with [constraints](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/constraints) — for example, a child of the camera node with a [world space orientation constraint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntransformconstraint/2867503-orientationconstraint) always returning identity, so that the node follows the camera's position but not its orientation.